# Working of sqrt() and pow() functions of math.h in C

Tags: c

`sqrt()` and `pow()` functions of `math.h` library in `C` are not defined for `integer` types but they don't *throw* any *error* but works fine for `integer` arguments, how does this work?

Comment: implicit conversion...

Comment: Any book or tutorial on `C` will have covered that at some point.

Comment: i actually don't understand the downvotes... if he didn't read a book this question shows up sooner or later. and it is something one **should** wonder about...

Comment: @Vogel612, one should do research (which includes finishing a tutorial) **before** rushing to SO to ask a question. That's a pedagogical point.

Comment: @Story Teller you got a point there. I didn't consider that thoroughly..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integers, when used in a context that expects floating point values, are implicitly converted to floating point values. And that's exactly what happens in your scenario, with functions that accept floating point parameters.

So, when you write:

```
#include <math.h>
....
int i;
double d = sqrt(i);
```

the integer `i` is converted to a `double` using the rules for implicit type conversion, and that `double` is passed to `sqrt()`.

Comment: Is **type promotion** the same thing, in this context?

Comment: When you pass them to *any* functions that take float or double arguments. Nothing special about these ones.

Comment: @EJP Right. I did not mean to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

implicit conversion from integer to floating point works fine in C, doesn't it?

if you pass an integer as argument to these functions it automatically will be converted to a floating point type.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out integers will be implicitly converted to floats when needed. Make sure you include the `math.h` header, though.